# JavaScript change font not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with changing font with JavaScript. The part of the code that change the font is working good and change all other element except the info text.
The problem occurs both with font size and font family change. To experience my problem select English then the right button is the info button. Click on it and you will see the target info text. Then click on settings button(this is the button next to the play button on the left side). Change the type of font size or font family and the main text will be change except info text. When i try to debug it the style is the target font family and everything looks good but the text just don't change. I found a solution with selection the whole info div but this affect my css style for the element. I also try to find a way to make head "h1" text automatically bigger than the others when changing it with javascirpt.

**Check the full code:**

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/YYKdje

https://jsfiddle.net/n4afc1yz/

```
 function changeFont(font){
                      gameRun=false;
    document.getElementById("pointsEnd").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    document.getElementById("points").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    document.getElementById("hightpoints").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    document.getElementById("outputMath").style.fontFamily = font.value;
        document.getElementById("SettingsBlock").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    document.getElementById("InfoText").style.fontFamily = font.value;
      console.log('Font changed with value: '+font.value);
       window.localStorage['font.value'] = font.value;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Its because you have some CSS for `*` which sets the font-family of all the elements on your page. When you reset it with JavaScript you only set it on the containers, but inside those containers, the child HTML elements still get the styling from the `*` CSS rule.

Comment: it might be better if you'd just apply a class to body and style everything according to that theme class instead of using inline styles + id's

Comment: @putvande
 Thanks a lot. It now works.